# Replace \ with " in XML using Groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy

I have below tag in my xml:

```xml
<Amt><InstdAmt Ccy=\USD\>4.38</InstdAmt></Amt>
```

I am getting above from an API response, which fetches data from AWS S3 bucket. But in AWS S3 bucket, the information is like below, which I am looking for.
I need to replace `\` before and after USD, with a `"`, like below:

```xml
 <Amt><InstdAmt Ccy="USD">4.38</InstdAmt></Amt>
```

With `\` I am not able to parse my XML.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I fetched the XML having <Amt><InstdAmt Ccy=\USD\>4.38</InstdAmt></Amt> and trying to parse it, def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(resp.toString()) . Getting the error like "Open quote is expected for attribute "Ccy" associated with an element type "InstdAmt"."

Comment: Can you 100% rule out, that this is not a X-Y-problem as in you are doing something wrong on the "fetching" side, that breaks your XML?

Comment: No, Please find a the portion of it:          
"                   <TxInfAndSts>",
   "                <StsId>WIRE</StsId>",
   "                <OrgnlInstrId>CPF31d0734657d84990b99d434610c2c971</OrgnlInstrId>",
   "                <OrgnlEndToEndId>ST</OrgnlEndToEndId>",
   "                <TxSts>ACSP</TxSts>",
   "                <OrgnlTxRef>",
   "                    <Amt>",
   "                        <InstdAmt Ccy=\"USD\">1.86</InstdAmt>",
   "                    </Amt>",
   "                </OrgnlTxRef>",
   "            </TxInfAndSts>",

Comment: So why not address the problem in the API? If the API messes things up beyond repair in one place, what prevents it messing up other places?

Comment: @Indranisgt, from java/groovy code point of view this `"<InstdAmt Ccy=\"USD\">1.86</InstdAmt>"` is correct string value that contains valid portion of xml. and you can parse this string as xml in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the following appears in your (non-)XML:

```
<Amt><InstdAmt Ccy=\USD\>4.38</InstdAmt></Amt>
```

But in comments you say that you are actually seeing

```
" <InstdAmt Ccy=\"USD\">1.86</InstdAmt>"
```

Escaping the internal quotes with backslashes is a perfectly reasonable thing to do when placing the string (as a whole) in quotes, and any process that reads this string should reverse the process and turn it back into the unescaped form:

```
<InstdAmt Ccy="USD">1.86</InstdAmt>
```

It looks to me as if you are incorrectly processing the data returned by the API.